# How to Group rows with the same string in a table on Telerik

Tags: telerik-grid

I have a table that has two fields: Item name and activity. Most of the items have the same name, but different activities. In my database I have a string for the field Item, and I need to create a table that has the activities grouped by the name of the item, and show in the table the "Item" name just once for all the rows that share the same Item name. I can't seem to find any information about this anywhere but I think it should be possible since it's such a basic feature. Does anyone know how to do that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHsjt.png

Comment: Please refer to do it programmatically - https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/grouping/setting-groups-programmatically.

Comment: Edit - Please refer to do it programmatically - https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/grouping/setting-groups-programmatically. I usually build the grid and allow the users to drag and drop the columns to group the data.